# How can i split this string using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

I have a string similar to:

```
"'a b | c'\,\,\,  'd | e f' ,,, 'g | h"
```

I want to use re.split to get the following list:

```
["a b|c", "d|e f", "g|h"]
```

I have tried the following but do not get the output i want, essentially i need to get rid all everything aside from the letters and the pipe operator, and split. One issue is that sometimes both ' and " are used:

```
re.compile(r'[\"\',][\W+]', re.UNICODE).split(txt.lower())
```

Comment: You can't do that with just `split()`. It will split the string, it won't modify the results to remove spaces in each element. You'll have to do that as an additional step after splitting.

Comment: Could you give an example of what the regexs should look like please ?

Comment: You do not need `re.UNICODE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the spaces around `|` as a separate step after splitting.

```
split = re.compile(r'[\"\',][\W+]', re.UNICODE).split(txt.lower())
cleaned = [re.sub(r'\s*\|\s*', '|', x) for x in split]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can just use `split`. You probably can't get rid of the first quote, or will end up with an empty first item.:

Here is one attempt, but it fails to remove the initial `'`:

```
re.split(r"(?<=.)'[^']+'", txt)
```

output: `["'a b | c", 'd | e f', 'g | h']`

An alternative with `findall`:

```
re.findall(r"'([^']+)'?", txt)
```

output: `['a b | c', 'd | e f', 'g | h']`

Comment: You're not getting the desired result. The question is about removing the spaces around `|`.

Comment: @Barmar OK I see, then it's definitely not achievable with split… and you need post-processing